# Configuring provider packages in web.xml with Jersey

Tags: java, web-services, jersey

I am working on a web service and I get very strange error.
This is the line from my `web.xml`:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>service</param-value>
</init-param>
```

As I know, `<param-value>` has to be referred in to the package my main application is. However, my application is in `rest.main` package, but the web service works only with the `service` value as defined above.

What is the problem, can somebody explain me these lines?

Comment: If your webservice resource exists in the `rest.main` package then the `param-value` needs to be set to `rest.main`

Comment: @PaulStatham as I said - if I set it to rest.main it doesn't work (HTTP 404). It only works with ,,service'' and that's the magic I am asking you about :)

Comment: What made you try with the service value? What is the structure of your project?

Comment: @PaulStatham I was doing everything from simple tutorial. First I named package ,,service.main'', then I renamed it and forgot about the parameter. I am trying to implement it now to another application and it doesn't work, that's why I got back to the root application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the application consists only resources and providers stored in particular packages, Jersey can scan them and register automatically.

```
<web-app>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    ...
</servlet>
...
</web-app>
```

The param-value refers to the packages which will be scanned automatically.

Comment: Still doesn't work (404 error). Where can I find that parameter defined? I want to know why it only works with ,,service''

Comment: So, what's the meaning of `org.foo.rest;org.bar.rest` here? are these actual values of your application?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/appendix-properties.html#appendix-properties-server) regarding the [`jersey.config.server.provider.packages`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ServerProperties.html#PROVIDER_PACKAGES) configuration property:

> Defines one or more packages that contain application-specific resources and providers. If the property is set, the specified packages will be scanned for JAX-RS root resources and providers.

### Servlet 2.x containers

This setting is frequently used in the `web.xml` deployment descriptor to instruct Jersey to scan these packages and register any found resources and providers automatically:

```xml
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.foo.myresources,org.bar.otherresources
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

With this setting, Jersey will automatically discover the resources and providers in the selected packages. By default, Jersey will recursively scan the sub-packages as well.

### Servlet 3.x containers

For Servlet 3.x containers, no `web.xml` is necessary at all. Instead, an [`@ApplicationPath`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) annotation can be used to annotate a custom [`Application`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) or [`ResourceConfig`](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs/2.22.2/jersey/org/glassfish/jersey/server/ResourceConfig.html) subclass and define the base application URI for all JAX-RS resources configured in the application.

Use the following to defined the packages that will be scanned:

```java
@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        packages("org.foo.myresources,org.bar.otherresources");
    }
}
```

For more details, check the [deployment section](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/deployment.html) of the Jersey documentation.

### Important

- Always use the qualified name of the package;
- Use `,` or `;` as delimiter when declaring multiple packages.

Comment: Do you have any examples of what real values should be used instead of  `org.foo.myresources,org.bar.otherresources`.... all examples use this very same example and I have no idea what to place there from a real project.

Comment: Finally found the delimiter for adding multiples.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the package name to the

Form an Example if I have placed my resource class in com.ft.resources package
then I have to add the package name in

```
<init-param> 
    <!-- For Jersey 2.x -->
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>com.ft.resources</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Hope this might resolve your issue